# angular js extending the if or switch statement

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

I have written a switch statement in angular js that returns a countries flag when it is typed in. e.g.

```
<div ng-switch-when="Argentina">
            <img src="Argentina.jpg" height="150" width="200">
        </div>
        <div ng-switch-when="USA">
            <img src="usa.jpg" height="150" width="200">
        </div>
```

but i was wondering how to do something like this. 
I've the following 3 sentences.

1. must contain capital letter
2. must contain lower case letter
3. must contain number

How would you turn each one from green to red when the condition is typed into the box.
if i typed in Ab the first 2 sentences would go green with the third red. Ab1 would make them all green. `..p././.,.` would make it red green red

so where it says Argentina i want some way of displaying maybe all the capitals but i know if put `ABCDEF etc` it will have to match them all rather than just 1

```
<span>
                    <strong> Password Rules </strong> <br/>
                    -must be between 8-16 characters <br/>
                    -contain an uppercase letter <br/>
                    -contain a lowercase letter <br/>
                    -contain a number <br/>
                    -contain a special character from this list ?!*.,:;(){}[]
                </span>
```

Comment: Search for [dirty-checking](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope). How is your code related with the question exactly?

Comment: @Bigood edited so it is now and not sure how dirty checking is relevant? i only need some simple logic and then it will work

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this in many ways. One is by `$watch`ing over scope whenever the sentence changed.

Other ways include ng-class, and another is ng-change.

A textChanged() method in controller can update a flag for each sentence:

  `<input type="text" ng-model="myText" ng-change="textChanged()">`

A CSS class may be selected for each type. `match1()` here would return true if first sentence is met. Have match2, match3 too...

  `<span ng-class="{red: match1(), green: !match1()}">Sentence</span>`

Reference:

- https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass
- https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange

Comment: might be a little bit of effort so appreciate it if you dont want to, but a jsfiddle would help me understand a lot better i reckon. mind creating one? thanksssss

Comment: @RagingBull take a look at the references I've just added. there are working samples of both techniques.

Comment: look at the code i just added i cant use ng directives on each sentence because they are all part of the same span but when i divide into paragraphs it screws it uo

Comment: angular can't style particular section sequences inside a single element. in fact you can't do it in css. angular will only expose what's in CSS and DOM. you're better at breaking it into multiple spans.`<p>` should work too, if you put ng-class on it.

Answer (score 0):

I made an example for you

```js
var myModule = angular.module('myModule', ['ngMessages']);


myModule.controller("Ctrl", Ctrl);

function Ctrl($scope) {

  $scope.data = {};
  $scope.onChange = function() {
    $scope.uppercase = /[A-Z]/.test($scope.data.password);
    $scope.lowercase = /[a-z]/.test($scope.data.password);
    $scope.number = /[0-9]/.test($scope.data.password);
    $scope.strlength = $scope.data.password >= 8 && $scope.data.password <= 16;
    $scope.special = /[\[\]\(\)\?\.!:;\*\{\}]/.test($scope.data.password);
  }
}
```

```css
.red {
  background-color: red;
}
.green {
  background-color: lime;
}
#myForm span {
  display: block;
}
#myForm {
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.9/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.9/angular-messages.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="myModule" ng-controller="Ctrl">
  <form name="myForm" id="myForm">
    <input type="text" name="password" ng-model="data.password" placeholder="Please enter" ng-change="onChange()" />
    <div>
      <span ng-class="{'red':!lowercase,'green':lowercase}">must contain an lowercase letter</span>
      <span ng-class="{'red':!uppercase,'green':uppercase}">must contain an uppercase letter</span>
      <span ng-class="{'red':!number,'green':number}">must contain a number</span>
      <span ng-class="{'red':!special,'green':special}">must contain a special character from this list ?!*.,:;(){}[]</span>
      <span ng-class="{'red':!strlength,'green':strlength}">must be between 8-16 characters</span>
    </div>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```